# Overrides controller form Prestashop 1.7.7

Tags: symfony, module, prestashop-1.7

Please, does anyone have an example of Admin controller override for Prestashop 1.7.7 (based on symfony)

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: It should suffice to create a class that extends one of the prestashop/src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin and then override the methods.

Comment: In practical terms, that is to say:
- I create a class in my module in the controllers directory (example: MyClass.php)
- After, I expand on the admin controller class I want, like MyClass extends AdminControlller ...

That's it ?

Thank you

Comment: I try to follow this : https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/admin-controllers/override-decorate-controller/ but i'm a laravel guy :)

Comment: Which controller are you trying to override? Prestashop is migrating (slowly) to symfony, which means there are two kinds of controllers: legacy and symfony. Give me the name of the controller (or the url relative to the backoffice) and may be able to help you further :)

Comment: @skaparate the link : admin146ckoabh/index.php/sell/orders/ or the controller is OrderController

Comment: Then you create a class inside your_module/src/Controller/Admin/YourNewController.php that extends the other one if you want modify some functionality and/or override the route entirely by adding a route to your_module/config/routes.yml. Check the folder prestashop/src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/config, there are all the symfony routes :).

Comment: If you can wait a little longer, I could create a sample module tonight (right now it's 11:57AM)

Comment: Ok good, thank @skap

Answer (score 4):

I created a sample module for this, which [can be download from here](https://github.com/skaparate/prestashop-sample-module) (under Releases).

The process to override the specific route `/adminXXXX/index.php/sell/orders/` is this:

1. You create a Symfony controller in your project (the code is a little further down). I create them inside `src/Controller`, which is the convention. This controller **must extend** the class `PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\FrameworkBundleAdminController`. I load my classes using composer auto loader, so here's the setup:

```json
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Skaparate\\": "src/"
  },
  "classmap": [
    "sk_testmodule.php"
  ],
  "exclude-from-classmap": []
},
```

2. You need to create a folder `config` in the root of your project. This is important because PrestaShop will load the routes and services from there.
3. Create a file called `routes.yml` inside the previously created folder.
4. Inside `routes.yml` define the route you want to override. In this case, the route is called `admin_orders_index`, hence we write this:

```yaml
   admin_orders_index:
     path: /sell/orders/
     # POST is required because admin_order_index is also setup as the grid reset return route.
     methods: [GET,POST]
     defaults:
        _controller: 'Skaparate\Controller\Admin\CustomOrdersController::indexAction'
       _disable_module_prefix: true
```

5. And finally, this is the actual Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace Skaparate\Controller\Admin;

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    die;
}

use PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\FrameworkBundleAdminController;
use PrestaShopBundle\Security\Annotation\AdminSecurity;
use PrestaShopBundle\Security\Annotation\ModuleActivated;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CustomOrdersController extends FrameworkBundleAdminController
{
    /**
     * Shows list of orders
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param OrderFilters $filters
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render(
            '@Modules/sk_testmodule/views/templates/admin/sell/order/index.html.twig',
            [
                'enableSidebar' => true,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

This project structure would be:

```
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── config
│   └── routes.yml
├── README.md
├── sk_testmodule.php
├── src
│   └── Controller
│       └── Admin
│           └── CustomOrdersController.php
└── views
    └── templates
        └── admin
            └── sell
                └── order
                    └── index.html.twig
```

Of course, you would need to create the file `views/templates/admin/sell/orders/index.html.twig`. I put it in that path to maintain PrestaShop structure, but it's not required.

For reference, Symfony routes are defined in `src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/config/routes` (relative to the PrestaShop installation).

Regards!

Comment: Yess, Thank @Skaparate :)
You save me, i will fork it and test it right now